# PHP PDF generation with database (MariaDB) data inclusion

Tags: database, php

I am searching a way to establish an automated generation of LaTeX PDF documents which will transfer data from MariaDB database. I found [this very interesting blog post](https://mike42.me/blog/how-to-generate-professional-quality-pdf-files-from-php) where author shows, how to use PHP to generate LaTeX documents. You can find his example on [Git-Hub](https://github.com/mike42/web-pdf).

Author shows, how to gather data from HTML forms using PHP `$_GET` method, so it crossed my mind... I think it would be possible to change his example to gather data from MariaDB database using PHP PDO and `$_POST` method instead? What do you think? Would this even work?

To me this seems the best way I found so far, but before I go and invest my time I want to ask you for your oppinion. Should I just use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) or [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) which I think only work with MySQL but not with MariaDB. Do you know any better solution?

Comment: I think this question is rather about PHP instead of LaTeX. And writing a script which writes database content to a LaTeX file should not be a problem (based on the GitHub code or using your own).

Comment: @epR8GaYuh I am glad to hear that it shouldn't be a problem! =)

Comment: You can use LuaTeX and directly connect to the database using [LuaSQL](https://keplerproject.github.io/luasql/).

Comment: @HenriMenke are there any tutorials about how to do this? If this is as good as it sounds like, this might be the best way! I am very interested! I looked into your link but I haven't found anything about MariaDB.

Comment: @71GA MariaDB is just the new name for MySQL, so all the MySQL documentation also applies to MariaDB.

Comment: I also found out about SQLTeX: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sqltex It looks promising! Maybe this is the easiest implementation of database queries into LaTeX documents.